# show that a sequence is non negative

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to show that : $g_n(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$ elements of $[a,b]$ And show that $g_n$ is monotone decreasing

When all you know is :

$g_n(x)= f(x)-f_n(x) ...$
 And $\{f_n \}$ is a non decreasing sequence meaning $f_n(x)\leq f_{n+1}(x)$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I guess $f$ is the pointwise limit of the sequence $f_n$?

Comment: Use that $f_n(x) \le f_{n+1}(x)$ and thus $f(x) - f_n(x) \ge f(x) - f_{n+1}(x)$

Comment: @JohnMa I tried f_n(x) <=f_{n+1}(x) =>

Comment: @nippon I see the idea but in wat way this implies that our G_n(x) is indeed non negative please ?!

Comment: @RyanEmmanuel given the fact that $f_n \rightarrow f$ we know that all $f_n \le f$. (this can be proven by contradiction). Then $g_n \ge 0$

Answer (score 0):

@JohnMa I tried f_n(x) <=f_{n+1}(x) =>   0 <= f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x)   until here I was fine but from here how to show that g_n(x) is non negative I've used so many scratch paper and it's for my thesis..  convergence theorem in reiman integral